# Passing method reference NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

I have a custom linked list class that has a find function which will go through the list until a test passes and return that node.

When calling:

```
firstHid = find(list, point::isNotVisible);
```

I get the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lnu/abc/-$$Lambda$1Xu6yqqPInUkBwCVFTE0OiCxD-o;

To test, I tried the following:

```
Predicate<Edge> test = point::isVisible;
```

Which still gives the same error. I tried using @Keep above the method as I thought the obfuscation might be the cause, but that did not fix it. I then checked minSDK for method references and it says that it works on any. I am not sure where to go from here.

The function looks like this:

```
public static <T> CustomLinkedList<T> find(CustomLinkedList<T> begin,
                                           Predicate<T> fn) {
    if (begin == null) { return null; }
    CustomLinkedList<T> iterator = begin;
    do {
       if (fn.test(iterator.data)){
            return iterator;
        }
        iterator = iterator.next;
    } while (iterator != begin && iterator != null);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using class Predicate from `java.util.function` package.

Documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support
states that this package is available only from API level 24 or higher and you are trying to run it on Android 5.0 with API 21.

You can still use Predicate from guava library or write your own interface.

Comment: This was correct, the error pointing to the lambda expression misled me, I thought it had to do with the method reference. I just implemented my own version of Predicate